# to read a xml file from disk using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a xml file stored in my hard disk
.i need to read data from that alter and add some data dynamically.
how can i do that?

Comment: You can do it i have seen that before although sucks http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-xml-parsing-on-mozilla-firefox-opera-browsers

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript in the browser cannot manipulate files on the client's hard drive (except for cookies, if you really want to count those).

If there is ever an instance where the above is not true, something is seriously wrong and there exists a major security hole.

Comment: Well, you can run JavaScript directly on the machine (not in the browser).